# Github's password/token stored in keychain and I can't push as another user

Tags: github, macos-sierra

So I have a personal and a work's Github account.
After some trial and error I found that the password to Github is stored in the macOS keychain.

That's annoying cause I can't define which account to associate the repo with even though I'd configured my user in `./git/config` for that repo.

And the reason it seems is that git will start searching for the global config first. So I removed the global config and keychain and pushed again.

It prompts me for the username password the first time, but stores that into the keychain **again** and uses that as the default user, not respecting the user I set in `./git/config`.

My ideal setup is to have the default user as my personal account and to have the work's account for specific work related repos. How do I do that?

I think the keychain is a bottleneck since it seems to be the first place git is using as authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, [here](https://superuser.com/a/1245296/96853)

`git config credential.username 'your username'`

This causes the cli to prompt for a password for that user and it will store that as another entry in the keychain. Will still have to configure git users with `git config user.name` etc so it knows which user to use.